# How to use exactOnSingleWordQuery with algoliyasearch-helper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algolia

As i read the doc of algoliyasearch-help it shows that we can use

`helper.setQuery('fruit').search();`

but I want to use `exactOnSingleWordQuery` and the syntax of using this in algoliya doc is:

```
results = index.search('query', {
  exactOnSingleWordQuery: 'word'
});
```

Comment: How is this related to firebase?

Comment: because i'm integrating Algoliya in Angular 6 + firebase project.

Comment: In that case you should include, in your question, how firebase is relevant for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setQueryParameter`:

`helper.setQueryParameter('exactOnSingleWordQuery', 'word')`

Source: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#set-a-parameter-later